# Change dpi setting on Zebra ZM400

Tags: label-printer

We have 30 or more older Zebra printers in our plant that are model Z4M.  New ones were ordered that are model ZM400 but it turns out that they are 300 DPI instead of 203 DPI like the old ones we have.  The problem is that the old 203 DPI labels don't print correctly at the higher DPI(they are smaller).  We can't change the label definitions because all of the old printers are still printing at 203 DPI.

There is a ZPL command in the manual that says:

"^MU also allows for printing at lower resolutions — 600 dpi printers are capable of printing at 300, 200, and 150 dpi; 300 dpi printers are capable of printing at 150 dpi."

Does this mean we are out of luck for printing our old 203 DPI labels with this printer?  Is there anything we can do other than get different printers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your are out of luck. Usually scaling that is used by Zebra needs dpi settings to be at integer multiplier. For 300 dpi that is 150dpi. 200 dpi would be at 2/3 and printer is just not smart enough for that.

Answer (score 0):

The ZM400 specifications say it has a 203dpi (8 dots/mm) printhead. The resolution specs say it will print 203dpi also.

http://www.scansmart.com/AIDC/zebra-zm400

PDF says same thing

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zebra.com%2Fid%2Fzebra%2Fna%2Fen%2Fdocumentlibrary%2Fmisc%2Fzm_automotive_flyer.File.tmp%2FZM_AutomotiveFlyer.pdf%26dvar1%3Dnull%26dvar2%3Dnull%26dvar3%3Dnull&ei=4hpSTNX_EoiPnwekzPnPAw&usg=AFQjCNHb54Dypx4sDPt5KPBiK5NMzGUXSA

Comment: There is an optional 300 and 600 dpi print head. The person that ordered the printer got the 300 dpi print head.

Comment: Go figure, the person that ordered it has no clue what to order.